# How to find a selected List cell indexPath in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm working on swiftUI list and slightly struggled in swiftUI list. How to get a selected cell indexPath similar **cellForRowAt** in **swift UITableViewDelegate** protocol API.

My list structure is:

```
struct ContactList: View {
    @ObservedObject var contactRepo = ContactRepository()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
             List(contactRepo.contacts){ contact in
                  ContactCell(data: contact)
              }
             .navigationTitle("Contacts")
        }
    }
}
```

List cell structure is:

```
struct ContactCell: View {
    var contactData: Contact
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                .data(urlStr: contactData.profileUrl)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .border(separatorColor, width: 1)
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .padding(10)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(contactData.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(appTextColor)
                Text(contactData.role)
                    .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .thin, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(appTextColor)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `List(_, selection:)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [`firstIndex(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/firstindex(of:)) method on the `contactRepo.contacts` array.

```swift
let contact: Contact = /* ... */
let index = contactRepo.contacts.firstIndex(of: contact)
```

If you want to insert something into the list, you can just modify the `contactRepo.contacts` array.